# How to use Material UI Select with react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, ref, react-hook-form

I've built a form in React using Material UI and React Hook Form. I'm trying to create a custom **`TextField`** element that works as a **Select Input**. I would like it to be an uncontrolled component with a **Ref** prop. I've tried to pass the `inputRef` prop as the Material UI and React Hook Form docs recommend but with no success.

```
            <TextField
              id="id"
              name="name"
              select
              native="true"
              className={classes.textField}
              label="label"
              margin="normal"
              variant="outlined"
              inputRef={register({ required: "Choose one option" })}
              error={!!errors.name}
            >
              <MenuItem value="">Choose one option</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="3">03</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="6">06</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="9">09</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="12">12</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="16">16</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="18">18</MenuItem>
            </TextField>
```

**One thing that I've found is that if I use the native *`select`* with *`ref`*, it works just fine.**

Besides, I tried to change the **`inputRef`** prop to a **`SelectProps`** one but it didn't work too.

Comment: Take a look at Controller: https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Using Select component from Material UI with react hook form need you to implement custom logic with a Controller https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller

Here is a reusable component that will hopefully simplify the code to use that Select component in your app:

```js
import React from "react";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form";

const ReactHookFormSelect = ({
  name,
  label,
  control,
  defaultValue,
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  const labelId = `${name}-label`;
  return (
    <FormControl {...props}>
      <InputLabel id={labelId}>{label}</InputLabel>
      <Controller
        as={
          <Select labelId={labelId} label={label}>
            {children}
          </Select>
        }
        name={name}
        control={control}
        defaultValue={defaultValue}
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
};
export default ReactHookFormSelect;
```

You can use it in your app like this:

```js
           <ReactHookFormSelect
              id="numero_prestacao"
              name="numero_prestacao"
              className={classes.textField}
              label="Em quantas parcelas?"
              control={control}
              defaultValue={numero_prestacao || ""}
              variant="outlined"
              margin="normal"
            >
              <MenuItem value="">Escolha uma opção</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="3">03 parcelas</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="6">06 parcelas</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="9">09 parcelas</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="12">12 parcelas</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="16">16 parcelas</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="18">18 parcelas</MenuItem>
            </ReactHookFormSelect>
```

Here is your codeSandBox updated with this component for the selects in the Information form:

https://codesandbox.io/s/unit-multi-step-form-kgic4?file=/src/Register/Information.jsx:4406-5238

Comment: How do you handle the onChange event?

Comment: In this case we don't have onChange bc the input is handled by the DOM, i.e. an uncontrolled component.

Comment: Yes, as @YungHK said, `react-hook-form` works with uncontrolled inputs. If you need the value of an input in your form you can use watch: https://react-hook-form.com/api#watch

Comment: To avoid the following error, you need to make sure you pass a valid defaultValue: `Material-UI: A component is changing the uncontrolled value state of Select to be controlled.
Elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa).
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled Select element for the lifetime of the component.`

Comment: Yes Paku that's work with valid default value thanks guys

Comment: I'm trying to use this with mui v5 + typescript: Type '{ as: Element; name: string; control: any; defaultValue: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { render: ({ field, fieldState, formState, }: { field: ControllerRenderProps<FieldValues, string>; fieldState: ControllerFieldState; formState: UseFormStateReturn<...>; }) => ReactElement<...>; } & UseControllerProps<...>'.

Answer (score 26):

**RHF v7 update**

Below is a minimal code example of Material UI `Select` in a RHF form:

```
const { formState, getValues, watch, register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
const { errors } = formState;
```

```
<TextField
  select
  fullWidth
  label="Select"
  defaultValue=''
  inputProps={register('currency', {
    required: 'Please enter currency',
  })}
  error={errors.currency}
  helperText={errors.currency?.message}
>
  {currencies.map((option) => (
    <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
      {option.label}
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</TextField>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: You demo have an error `A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled`

Comment: @Randall this is a terrible warning from MUI because RHF uses uncontrolled mode by default, in uncontrolled mode, `value` is undefined and the `defaultValue` is optional, but in this MUI component, you need to provide one explicitly for some reason. Anyway I fixed my answer, it should be working properly now.

Comment: What is the difference between this approach and the Controller component (accepted answer) approach ?

Comment: @NearHuscarl Use Controller from react-hook-form

Comment: @NearHuscarl clearest example I found so far, thank you very much

Comment: Thanks. This is what I needed. This is a workable example using MUI v5 and react-hook-form

Answer (score 11):

Accepted version is correct but outdated.

At least in the version that I'm using: `"react-hook-form": "^7.30.0"` you should use the `render` parameter.

Here is the "updated" version that perfectly works for me:

```
        <FormControl>
          <InputLabel id="level-label">Level</InputLabel>
          <Controller
            name="level"
            id="level"
            defaultValue={level}
            control={control}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <Select labelId="level-label" {...field}>
                <MenuItem value={0}>0</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={1}>1</MenuItem>
              </Select>
            )}
          />
          <FormHelperText error={true}>{errors.level?.message}</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
```

The important here is to propagate the `field` properties down to the child element (*Select* in our case)

PS. I don't think you need a separate component for it, it is pretty straight forward.

[Updated]
Here is a full code of one of my dialog. As per request from Deshan.

```
import {
  Box, Chip, FormControl, Input, Stack,
} from '@mui/material';
import { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import debounce from '../@utils/debounce';
import useRawParams from '../@utils/useRawParams';
import { useBrandsSearchQuery } from '../data/products';
import { SearchRoute } from '../SBRoutes';
import LoadingDiv from './LoadingDiv';
import SBDialog from './SBDialog';
import { useSearchBarContext } from '../contexts/SearchBarContext';

const context = { suspense: false };
/**
 * Show the modal dialog with the list of brands, and search box for it
 * Eeach brand will be as a link, for the SEO purposes
 */
export default function AllBrandsDialog({ open, setOpen }) {
  const [t] = useTranslation();
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [brands, setBrands] = useState([]);
  const params = useRawParams(true);
  const paramsBrands = params.brands?.split(',') || [];
  const { setFilterActive } = useSearchBarContext();

  const variables = useMemo(() => (query.length ? {
    filterText: query,
  } : null), [query]);

  const [{ data, fetching: loading }] = useBrandsSearchQuery({ variables, pause: Boolean(!variables), context });
  const debounceSetQuery = useCallback(debounce(200, (text) => {
    setQuery(text);
  }));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!data || !open) return;
    setBrands(data.brands || []);
  }, [data, open]);

  return (
    <SBDialog open={open} setOpen={setOpen} title={t('Search and select a brand')}>
      <Stack direction="column" spacing={2}>
        <FormControl>
          <Input
            id="tagSearch"
            placeholder={t('Start typing to see the brands')}
            onChange={(e) => debounceSetQuery(e.target.value)}
            autoFocus={true}
          />
        </FormControl>
        <Box display="grid" width={220} height={300} overflow="auto" gap={1} position="relative">
          {brands?.map((brand) => (
            <Chip
              component={Link}
              key={brand.id}
              disabled={paramsBrands.indexOf(brand.url) > -1}
              to={SearchRoute.generatePath({
                ...params,
                brands: [...paramsBrands, brand.url],
                page: undefined,
              })}
              size="small"
              label={brand.nicename}
              variant="outlined"
              onClick={() => {
                setOpen(false);
                setFilterActive(false);
              }}
              clickable={true}
            />
          ))}
          {loading && <LoadingDiv modal={true} />}
        </Box>
      </Stack>
    </SBDialog>
  );
}

AllBrandsDialog.propTypes = {
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  setOpen: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: Hi @Kostanos, Can you please share a working code sample of this?? TIA

Comment: Hey @Deshan-Charuka, I just updated my answer with a full code example from one of my dialog that I have. I hope it helps you.

Comment: @Kostanos your "full code example" doesn't even include the use of react-hook-form.  Why did you add it your post, it adds nothing to your answer, its totally off-topic. Pus your initial answer uses "Controller" component and "control" object, without showing where these would have come from - ok the Controller is just an import, but what about control.  Now THAT would have been a great "full code example" ...

Comment: @AndyLorenz it is true, in my "full code" example I don't have a component with a render. But you can add this component to that example from my previous code sample. The goal of this code was to show how I realize form in general

Comment: Worked for us on `"react-hook-form": "^7.50.1"` and `"@mui/material": "^5.14.17"`, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Here my code that working, hope it can help, need to use `setValue`

```
  <TextField
    fullWidth
    inputRef={register({
      name: 'name',
    })}
    select
    onChange={e => setValue('name', e.target.value, true)}
    label={label}
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
  >
    {options.map((option) => (
      <MenuItem key={option.label} value={option.value}>
        {option.label}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </TextField>
```

Here using native select, do not need setValue, but value alway string

```
<TextField
    fullWidth
    select
    SelectProps={{
      native: true,
      inputProps: { ref: register, name: 'name' }
    }}
    label={label}
    defaultValue={defaultValue}
  >
    {options.map((option) => (
      <option key={option.label} value={option.value}>
        {option.label}
      </option>
    ))}
  </TextField>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example that uses Material-UI with React hook form. You need to add the validation in 'inputRef' prop of TextField. Also you need to add 'onChange' function to keep the state updated. 'shouldValidate' will trigger the validation.

```
  <TextField
    select
    name='city'
    inputRef={register({ required: true })}
    onChange={e => setValue('city', e.target.value, { shouldValidate: true })}
    label="City"
    defaultValue="">
    {cityList.map((option, index) => (
      <MenuItem key={index} value={option}>
        {option}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </TextField>

  {errors.city && <ErrorText>City is required</ErrorText>}
```

Answer (score 0):

✔ I came across this same issue, and this is how i solved mine:

```
<Select ... onChange={e => register({ name: 'academicLevel', value: e.target.value })}/>
```

[more info](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/380)

Answer (score 0):

When you using react-hook-form with material UI, you don´t need to use onChange and setState. Only use inputRef and all works!

Comment: the question is about using the select

Answer (score 0):

Just need to pass the register to the Input Ref

```
 <Select
   variant="outlined"
   name="reason"
   inputRef={register({ required: true })}
  >
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `mui-react-hook-form-plus`

Here is an example:

```
import { HookSelect, useHookForm } from 'mui-react-hook-form-plus';

const defaultValues = {
        person: {
            firstName: 'Atif',
            lastName: 'Aslam',
            sex: '',
        },
};

const App = () => {
    const { registerState, handleSubmit } = useHookForm({
        defaultValues,
    });

    const onSubmit = (_data: typeof defaultValues) => {
        alert(jsonStringify(_data));
    };

    return (
        <HookSelect
            {...registerState('person.sex')}
            label='SEX'
            items={[
                { label: 'MALE', value: 'male' },
                { label: 'FEMALE', value: 'female' },
                { label: 'OTHERS', value: 'others' },
            ]}
        />
    )
}
```

Repo: https://github.com/adiathasan/mui-react-hook-form-plus

Demo: https://mui-react-hook-form-plus.vercel.app/?path=/docs/

Answer (score 0):

save select state to `useState` and pass state to `react-hook-form` register

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { Select, MenuItem } from '@mui/material';

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  age: yup.number().required('Age is required'),
});

function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });

  const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
        id="demo-simple-select"
        {...register('age')}
        value={age}
        label="Age"
        onChange={handleChange}
      >
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </Select>

      {errors.age && <p>{errors.age.message}</p>}

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```