# React Select does not trigger when onChange

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to access the value of a Select with the event onChange so I can update another Select, but the Select doesn't trigger onChange. You can find the code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-template-forked-e3sf9?file=/src/index.js:0-1403):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import {
  FormControl,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
  InputLabel,
  FormHelperText
} from "@material-ui/core";

function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, errors, control } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
  const [test, setTest] = useState(0);
  const handleChange = (stateFunction, event) => {
    if (event) {
      console.log(event);
      setTest(event.target.value);
    }
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <FormControl variant="outlined" required>
        <InputLabel>Test</InputLabel>
        <Controller
          as={
            <Select width={"300px"} onChange={handleChange(setTest, this)}>
              <MenuItem value="1">One</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="2">Two</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="3">Three</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          }
          control={control}
          defaultValue="1"
          name="brandId"
          rules={{ required: "Marca es requerido" }}
        />
        <FormHelperText error={true}>
          {errors.brand && errors.brand.message}
        </FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Any idea where the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: i'm not sure, but once you move the Select section to outside of Controller, it works.

Comment: i think you should follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63246774/1435722

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan Thanks man, that made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call function like `onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(onSubmit)}`.
In your current code, `handleSubmit` is called as soon as the component is rendered because you called it directly like this `handleSubmit(onSubmit)`

Final Output:

[image]

[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-template-forked-rgcq5)

I have also edited the  `<SpecialInput/>` component to handle input.

Possible fix:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import {
  FormControl,
  // SelectField,
  MenuItem,
  Select,
  InputLabel,
  FormHelperText
} from "@material-ui/core";
import SpecialInput from "./SpecialInput";
function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, errors, control } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("hi");
  };
  const [test, setTest] = useState(0);
  const [selectedItem, setItem] = useState(1);
  const handleChange = (stateFunction, event) => {
    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("hi");
      // setTest(event.target.value);
      console.log("test:", test);
    }
  };

  const onTextChange = (event) => {
    setTest(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={(event) => handleChange(onSubmit, event)}>
      <FormControl variant="outlined" required>
        <InputLabel>Test</InputLabel>
       
        <Controller
          render={(props) => (
            <Select
              value={selectedItem}
              onChange={(event) => setItem(event.target.value)}
            >
              <MenuItem value="1">One</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="2">Two</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value="3">Three</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          )}
          control={control}
          defaultValue="1"
          name="brandId"
          rules={{ required: "Marca es requerido" }}
        />
        <FormHelperText error={true}>
          {errors.brand && errors.brand.message}
        </FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
      <SpecialInput handleChange={onTextChange} test={test} />
      <input type="submit" />
      <h1>{`Test Value: ${test}`}</h1>
      <h1>{`Select Value: ${selectedItem}`}</h1>
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I just tried that but it doesn't trigger the onChange event.

Comment: do you need Controller for react-hook-form?

Comment: @WilliamWang I do.

Comment: one more thing, you forgot to use ```event.preventDefault()``` in ```handleSubmit()``` method, because of that whenever the submit was pressed the entire page was getting refreshed.
Try updated code. I checked it and and it is workring

Comment: @KetanRamteke Thank you for the throughout description, very appreciated! The only thing is that I cannot capture the onChange event of the Select. Any suggestion on how to do that?